# Mutable array of immutable length in D

Tags: arrays, syntax, d, immutability, immutablearray

Is it possible in D to have a mutable array of which the length is not known at compile time to have a static length?

```
void testf(size_t size) {
    int immutable([]) testv = new int[](a);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, at least not unless you provide your own array wrapper. You could do something like:

```
struct ImmutableLength {
     int[] array;
     alias array this; // allow implicit conversion to plain array
     this(int[] a) { array = a; } // initialization from plain array
     @property size_t length() { return array.length; }
     @disable @property void length(size_t) {}
     @disable void opOpAssign(string op: "~", T)(T t) {}
     @disable void opAssign(int[]) {}
 }
```

Notice the disabled length setter and append operator which pretty much implements what you want.

```
            auto i = ImmutableLength([1,2,3]); // declare it like this
```

Comment: BTW You might also need to @disable opAssign(int[] rhs) because I think alias this lets that happen too.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the native array type in a custom type which restricts access to the `length` property:

```
struct FixedLengthArray(T)
{
    T[] arr;
    alias arr this;

    this(size_t size) { arr = new T[size]; }

    @property size_t length() { return arr.length; }
}

void main()
{
    auto arr = FixedLengthArray!int(10);
    arr[1] = 1;               // OK
    arr[2..4] = 5;            // OK
    assert(arr.length == 10); // OK
    arr.length = 12;          // Error
}
```

Comment: but `arr~=1` will compile and increase the length